# The new Copenhagen wheel - a worthwhile investment?

Tags: conversion, electric-bike

I've been looking to reduce how much I sweat on my commute to work, and I've been looking into electric bicycles. Upon looking, I saw the [copenhagen wheel](https://superpedestrian.com/): an all-in-one electric bicycle conversion kit. I'd prefer to go with the most cost efficent method. Does anyone have any experience with it? Is it more practical to buy a complete electric bike or to use a conversion kit?

Comment: Not really on topic as it's basically a product recommendation and opinion based. However, personally I think the copenhagen wheel and other electric bike technologies add a lot more complication without giving huge advantages. Current laws in many countries require that electric power cut out around 30 km/h, which is pretty close to how fast I go without a complicated battery and electric motor.  The added cost, does not provide a significant amount of benefit.

Comment: @Kibbee perhaps we can suggest how to make the question on topic? As to the dislike over electric bikes, the lifecycle carbon footprint is nearly identical to regular cycling, and not everyone is interested in fitness.

Comment: Depends how technical you are.  A kit works well if you have an existing frame and components that you like and want to keep using.   A dedicated ebike works better if you just want to click in a battery and go.   Your budget is also relevant,  a kit+buying a bike costs more than buying a complete ebike.

Comment: @Criggie the Copenhagen wheel is a self-contained electric wheel.  All you need to know is how to change a rear wheel.

Comment: I am voting to close because the linked page tells me that the product is not released yet, so the question is hypothetical.

Comment: At $1000 for the wheel, it isn't cost effective against existing hub motor kits which can be purchased for around $400. Furthermore, embedding the controller + battery in the wheel makes the wheel much heavier and limits the amount of battery space available (note that the website doesn't list the amp-hour capacity of the battery). A good conceptual idea but not practical.

Comment: @RoboKaren I see that it doesn't list the amp hour spec, but, seeing as how it's a motor that provides only assistance, I somehow belive their 40 km distance rating at 30 km/h

Comment: That's most probably with vigorous pedaling on the part of the cyclist. In which case, my non-electric bicycle can do that just as well. In fact, I could do 100km at 30km/hr if I ate enough wheaties and trained real hard. :-)

Comment: @RoboKaren well, it does accept a cassette and claims to 'provide assistance based on how strongly you pedal', so I feel that I could assume that my 6 mile trek to and from work up and down his could be done fairly easily by any e-bike

Comment: @RoboKaren - $400 for a wheel and no battery is not an apples to apples comparison as the Copenhagen wheel includes a battery.

Answer (score 3):

Some of your questions are not answerable, so I will only focus on what can be answered.

> Does anyone have any experience with it?

No one has any real experience yet as the wheels are still on pre-order.  A friend pre-ordered nearly 2 years ago and is still waiting.  That said, you live near their headquarters (Cambridge, Mass) apparently you can demo a unit.

> Is it more practical to buy a complete electric bike or to use a
>   conversion kit?

This depends on what you mean by "practical" and what your use case is.  If you are planning on long distance commutes (e.g., 40+ km) with a high assist level, then it will not be practical as the battery housed within the wheel may not provide enough range.

If by "practical" you mean easy to convert an existing bike, the answer could be yes if your bike matches their required specs.

For geared bikes your will need rim brakes on the rear wheel (no disc brakes) and a rear hub spacing of 135 mm (road bikes are 130mm and will not work unless you spread the frame - difficult and requires steel frames).  If you are fixed or single speed your rear spacing will need to have a standard track hub spacing (120mm).

You will also need a smart phone in order to interact and change the settings on the wheel.

If any of these are a deal breaker then it is not practical for you.

In terms of pricing it is very competitive relative to existing electric bike or existing conversion kits.  Assuming it actually ships and works as advertised.

---

***NOTE:** For those unfamiliar the Copenhagen wheel is self contained (battery and motor are housed within a large hub)  rear wheel which you swap out on an existing bike.  Assuming your bike (or bikes) is compatible, this makes turning an existing bike into an electric bike a relatively quick and straight forward conversion. All controls are done via a smart phone application and bluetooth*

Comment: A few people have tried it

Answer (score 1):

If money is of little consequence, by all means, acquire an electric bike for your work commute and keep your current bicycle as it is. The electric bike is more likely to have a longer lasting battery and integrated controls.

The conversion kit on the other hand, will be less expensive and could probably be swapped between multiple bikes. It seems like a generally more convenient route.